# No (complete) omniORB installation was not found. Please provide OMNIORB4_DIR:

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm installing some software required for work. According to the installation instructions (I've done it some months ago and it worked) running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libomniorb4-dev
```

Should install the dependencies, at first, I got a problem with no found on libomniorb4. I first searched the libomniorb.deb and installed it using `sudo apt install ./package-name.deb` and I did it also with libomnithread4 because I got an error on the first one.

As it didn't work, I managed to run `sudo apt-get install libomniorb4-dev` in the end activating the following ticks:
[image]

I tried compiling with cmake but got the following:

```
No (complete) omniORB installation was not found. Please provide OMNIORB4_DIR:
  - through the GUI when working with ccmake, 
  - as a command line argument when working with cmake e.g. 
    cmake .. -DOMNIORB4_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/omniORB-4.0.5 
Reason:
  OMNIORB4_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/include
  OMNIORB4_LIBRARY_omniORB4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniORB4.so
  OMNIORB4_LIBRARY_omnithread: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnithread.so
  OMNIORB4_IDL_COMPILER: OMNIORB4_IDL_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

I tried uninstalling everything with apt remove and reinstalling with the apt-get command. I tried `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and even the `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I also did: `sudo apt-get install -f`

So I tried to find the library itself and did:

```
find /usr/ -iname "*omni*"
/usr/include/omniconfig.h
/usr/include/omnithread
/usr/include/omniORB4
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniServer.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniORBcompat.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniORB.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/internal/omniCurrent.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/internal/omniIdentity.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniConnectionMgmt.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniServant.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniAsyncInvoker.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniObjRef.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniConnectionData.hh
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniIOR.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniURI.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniZIOP.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniTransport.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniInterceptors.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniutilities.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniTypedefs.hh
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniInternal.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniPolicy.h
/usr/include/omniORB4/omniObjKey.h
/usr/include/omnithread.h
/usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja
/usr/lib/thunderbird/omni.ja
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/omniConnectionMgmt4.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/omniZIOPDynamic4.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/omnithread4.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/omniDynamic4.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/omniORB4.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/omniZIOP4.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnithread.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniConnectionMgmt4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnisslTP4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOPDynamic4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniDynamic4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniORB4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniORB4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnisslTP4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnithread.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniORB4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnithread.so.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniDynamic4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOP4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniConnectionMgmt4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniConnectionMgmt4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOP4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniCodeSets4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniConnectionMgmt4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnithread.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOPDynamic4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniDynamic4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniORB4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniCodeSets4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOP4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnisslTP4.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOPDynamic4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniDynamic4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomnisslTP4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniCodeSets4.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOP4.so.2.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniZIOPDynamic4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libomniCodeSets4.a
/usr/share/doc/libomniorb4-2
/usr/share/doc/libomnithread4
/usr/share/doc/libomniorb4-dev
/usr/share/doc/libomnithread4-dev
/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/sb-omni-surround-5.1.conf
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/include/config/usb/serial/omninet.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic/include/config/usb/serial/omninet.h
```

I also searched using the `apt-cache search` option and installed: omniorb-idl

Comment: Choose the package with more care, they are not consistent. libomniorb4-2, omniorb-nameserver, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get install omniidl
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this: https://code.google.com/archive/p/incub/wikis/UbuntuInstallation.wiki

If what you’re trying to build is Incub then it’s probably fine to ignore that. If not, please clarify— what are you building with cmake?

Comment: I'm not trying to install incub. It's a program made by my company that uses omniorb. however I tried all the omniorb packages from your link (`omniorb4 omniidl4 omniorb4-nameserver libomniorb4-dev`) and got: `E: Unable to locate package omniorb4
E: Unable to locate package omniidl4
E: Unable to locate package omniorb4-nameserver
`.